# Can I re-use IP address of a failed Domain Controller for a new Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

One Domain Controller in my domain failed and can't be recovered. I've seized the FSMO roles onto the surviving DC, and performed metadata cleanup.

Now, I'm in the process of installing a replacement DC. I plan on using a new name, but can I re-use the late DC's IP Address? Will there be complications if I do so?

PS: We're using Windows Server 2008R2, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make sure all references to the old IP are removed from any AD-integrated DNS zones BEFORE joining the machine to the domain.

Comment: You can even use the same name. Once you removed anything from AD

Comment: Removing failed DC's from AD: http://www.petri.co.il/delete_failed_dcs_from_ad.htm